# Read Dialog Box Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to see if there is anyway I can get Java to read aloud the content of a dialog box, similar to Windows Narrator.

Currently, I am only able to get the title of the window read aloud.  Is there anyway to get the entire contents of the dialog box read aloud?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you have a look [How to Support Assistive Technologies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/access.html)?

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!